# Drawing pixels on Canvas with BufferedImage not filling the whole Canvas

Tags: java

I'm trying to draw pixels on a Canvas using a BufferedImage. In my Canvas constructor I am initializing the image and pixel array like so:

```
public MyCanvas() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setSize(size);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);

    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
}
```

I draw every render by doing:

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        pixels[i] = 0xFFFFFF;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

I'm expecting that my canvas is filled with white pixels, but I get black borders on the right and bottom of the white area, i.e. it's doesn't seem to be filling my entire canvas, or it has some negative offset. I've checked that the length of the pixel array is WIDTH * HEIGHT. I'm putting the canvas into a JPanel with BorderLayout.CENTER, in a JFrame.

EDIT:

Changing

```
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
```

to

```
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

makes it do what I expect. However I don't understand why I have to fetch the canvas size when I have set the size myself (to WIDTH, HEIGHT), and it doesn't seem to be the same as the size I gave it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're setting the color for the rectangle fill.

Try this:

```
Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
// g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
// g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

Comment: The purpose is not to fill the whole canvas with white pixels really, but I'm concerned that it doesn't draw to the whole canvas.

Comment: I changed the drawImage parameters.  That should be the entire canvas, no matter if it's resized or not.